# Как программа копирует экземпляры разных классов?

Tags: c++, классы, конструктор, преобразование-типов

Есть два класса: A и B.

Если производится копирование обьектов одного и того же класса, то вызывается конструктор копирования и копирует соответствующие поля. А вот если произвести такое:

```
A a;
B b;

a = (A)b;
```

Как работает копирование в этом случае?

Comment: Что такое `A` и `B`? В общем случае `(A)b` просто невозможно. Соответственно никакого копирования тут не будет - код просто некорректен.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если в классе `B` имеется доступный оператор преобразования типов из типа класса `B`  в тип класса `A`, то он вызывается в выражении приведения типа `(A)b`, результатом которого является временный объект типа `A`. Этот временный объект присваивается объекту `a` с помощью копирующего или перемещающего оператора присваивания в предложении

```
a = (A)b;
```

Вот демонстрационная программа

```
#include <iostream>

struct A
{
    A & operator =( const A & )
    {
        std::cout << "A::operator =" << std::endl;
        return *this;
    }
};

struct B
{
    operator A() const
    {
        std::cout << "operator B::A()" << std::endl;
        return A();
    }
};

int main() 
{
    A a;
    B b;

    a = ( A )b;

    return 0;
}
```

Ее вывод на консоль

```
operator B::A()
A::operator =
```

Оператор преобразования может быть объявлен также со спецификатором функции `explicit`. Например,

```
explicit operator A() const;
```

Или более "запутанный" пример преобразований, когда оператор преобразования перегружен для `lvalue` и `rvalue`.

```
#include <iostream>

struct A
{
    A() 
    { 
        std::cout << "A::A()" << std::endl;
    }

    A( const A & )
    {
        std::cout << "A::A( const A & )" << std::endl;
    }

    A & operator =( const A & )
    {
        std::cout << "A::operator =( const A & )" << std::endl;
        return *this;
    }

    A & operator =( A && )
    {
        std::cout << "A::operator =( A && )" << std::endl;
        return *this;
    }
};

struct B
{
    explicit operator A() const &
    {
        std::cout << "operator A() &" << std::endl;
        return A();
    }

    explicit operator A() const &&
    {
        std::cout << "operator A() &&" << std::endl;
        return A();
    }
};

int main() 
{
    A a;
    B b;

    a = ( A )b;

    std::cout << std::endl;

    a = ( A )B();

    return 0;
}
```

Вывод этой программы на консоль

```
A::A()
operator A() &
A::A()
A::operator =( A && )

operator A() &&
A::A()
A::operator =( A && )
```

Например, для предложения

```
a = ( A )B();
```

вызывается оператор преобразования для `rvalue` временного объекта, созданного вызовом `B()`,

```
operator A() &&
```

Затем внутри этого оператора создается временный объект типа `A`

```
A::A()
```

Этот временный объект с помощью перемещающего оператора присваивания присваивается объекту `a`

```
A::operator =( A && )
```

Самый простой вариант - это когда в классе `A` имеется конструктор преобразования. Например,

```
#include <iostream>

struct A
{
    A() {}

    explicit A( const struct B & );

    A & operator =( const A & )
    {
        std::cout << "A::operator =( const A & )" << std::endl;
        return *this;
    }

};

struct B
{
};

A::A( const B & )
{
    std::cout << "A::A( const B & )" << std::endl;
}

int main() 
{
    A a;
    B b;

    a = ( A )b;

    return 0;
}
```

Вывод программы на консоль

```
A::A( const B & )
A::operator =( const A & )
```

В определении класса `A` объявлен преобразующий конструктор

```
explicit A( const struct B & );
```

который вызывается при приведении типов в выражении `( A )b`

И, наконец, если класс `B` является производным от класса `A`, то вы можете просто записать

```
a = b;
```

В этом случае объект класса `B` неявно преобразуется в объект класса `A` и вызывается копирующий оператор присваивания класса `A`.

Comment: Спасибо за развернутый ответ)

Comment: @Alerr Не за что . Смотрите мой дополненный ответ.